# Validation rule confused

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to have Checkbox 2 be **eligible** to be checked only if Checkbox 1 is TRUE.

My validation rule is: IF (Checkbox_1__c = TRUE)....I know I'm missing something but don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation rules are meant to tell us when data is invalid. If the result of the validation formula is true, then the validation rule triggers and prevents DML from completing.

In your case, data is invalid when Checkbox 2 is True and Checkbox 1 is False.

`AND(Checkbox_2__c, NOT(Checkbox_1__c))`

There's no need to check if a boolean value (such as a checkbox) is equal to true or false. Since they're already booleans, just use them directly.

Let's do a quick evaluation of that validation rule to make sure it's correct.

1. `AND(True, NOT(False))`
2. `AND(True, True)`
3. `True`

So on Checkbox2 = true and Checkbox1 = false, we end up being true, and the validation triggers. So far so good.

What about checkbox1 being true?

1. `AND(checkbox2, NOT(True))`
2. `AND(checkbox2, false)`
3. `false`

In this case, it doesn't matter what checkbox2 is. `False && <anything> = false`. The validation rule does not trigger. Just like what you wanted.

The same can be said if checkbox2 is false (we also end up in a `False && <anything>`) scenario.

Comment: Thank you! This was a very helpful explanation! Validation rules do a Twister on my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below validation rule

```
NOT(Checkbox_1__c) && Checkbox_2__c
```

This means if `Checkbox_1__c` field value is not true and the user checks `Checkbox_2__c` then the validation throws an error.

Note that in Salesforce, you write validation rule such a way that it displays the error if the condition meets.

This [trailhead Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules) is a great resource to learn validation rules.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!